# Wordpress. How can I display specific number of posts?

Tags: wordpress

For example, I want to display on one page last 3 posts. On other page I want to display next 5 posts etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in wordpress function wp_get_recent_posts() and pass in a 'numberposts' parameter to specify how many recent posts you want to display.

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

You can also use an if statement to tell it to show a different number of posts depending on which page it is. You pass the is_page() function the page id as a parameter. For example --

```
if (is_page(123)) { 
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3)
} elseif (is_page(456)) { 
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5) 
} else { 
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must learn query_posts..

posts_per_page for last 3 posts
offset for next 5 posts

Check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)